# Check if buffername is equal to file name

Tags: org-mode, org-export, string, equality

I'm trying to autoexport a file from orgmode to html, so I decided to make a function to check the major mode of the buffer and check if the buffer has open the file that I want to export but when I try it the function export all the orgmode files and not the one that I want.

Here is the code:

```
(defun org-mode-export-hook()
"Auto export html"
(when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (when (eq buffer-file-name "/home/rafa/org/to-read.org")
        (org-twbs-export-to-html t))))
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Learn to indent your code. You'll notice that the second condition is ignored, as its closing parenthesis goes before the export.

Comment: sorry I was writing from my phone and indent not works well, here it's my real function.

Comment: You may want t consider using ’derived-mode-p’ instead of testing with eq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't want to test string-content equality using `eq`. Use **`equal`** instead.  Or you can use `string-equal`, if you are sure that `buffer-file-name` will return a string in your context.

See the Elisp manual, nodes [Equality Predicates](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Equality-Predicates.html) and [Text Comparison](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Comparison.html).

Second, consider using function `buffer-file-name` instead of variable `buffer-file-name`.  Not necessary, but a good habit, IMO.  (And you can use it in other contexts, where you pass a `BUFFER` argument.)

Third, you might need/want to use function `buffer-file-truename` instead of `buffer-file-name`.

Only the first is important, probably: You cannot test string content using `eq`.